# How to use ng-options with controller as syntax and an Enum in my Data Layer

Tags: c#, angularjs, enums

I am trying to pass back a numeric value from a drop down list to my object that is being sent to the back end using $http.post. It seems like the perfect place to use ng-options with an array of objects in my controller.
I have been trying to get the syntax right but have not been able to get it from the documentation or searching through old posts. I cannot even get the drop down list populated with the names from the array in my controller. The object that I pass back to the web API controller needs to have a numeric value because the property on the C# model that the Drop down list correlates to is actually an enum on the data model.

My markup looks like this:

```
 <select ng-model="vm.user.userRole" ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.id">
                </select>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  (function() {
"use strict";

angular.module('app').controller("userEntryController", ["$http","$timeout", userEntryController]);

function userEntryController($http, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.user = {}
    vm.newUser = {};
    vm.saving = true;
    vm.successMessage = null;
    vm.errorMessage = null;

    vm.saveUser = function () {
        $http.post("http://localhost:55928/api/Users/", vm.user)
            .then(function() {
                //success
                vm.saving = false;
                vm.successMessage = "User has been updated ....";
                    $timeout(function() {
                        vm.saving = false;
                        vm.successMessage = null;
                    }, 1500);
                },
                function() {
                    //error
                    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to save User ...";
                });
    }

    vm.roles = [
        {id:1, name:"Admin"},
        {id:2, name:"Doctor"},
        {id: 3, name: "Therapist"},
        {id:4, name: "Patient"}  
    ];
}
 })();
```

The C# model looks like this

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace PTWebApp.DataModels
{
    public class User
   {
    public User()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Role UseRole { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }        
    public string Telephone2 { get; set; }
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string InjuryType { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string DeaNumber { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } 
  }
}
public enum Role
{
   Admin = 1,
   Doctor = 2,
   Therapist = 3,
   Patient = 4
 }
```

I would love a nudge in the right direction, I am having a hard time coming up with the right way to do it with the controller as syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research and a bit of help I found that when using as the track by must be implied or it will break the select logic.

Here is my fixed mark up:

```
  <select ng-model="vm.user.useRole" ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in vm.roles">
```